# App link assistant error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-app-links

I want to use **app link** in order to navigate to my app after payment & for this reason I use app link assistant but in second step when I want to select activity, I get error below !!

***as you see image below I have "onCreate" method***

[image: as you see image below I have "onCreate" method]

does any one know how to resolve this error?

Comment: same here, any solution?

Comment: using android studio chipmunk (2021.2.1 Patch 1)

Answer (score 0):

As this is used in activity so try to fetch the link in activity which is connected to the fragment and then redirect it to the fragment using intent or by any other method